# Yii -CExistValidator for external key

Tags: yii

In a simple project with Yii I have a model:

Checkins.php

```
 * The followings are the available columns in table 'checkins':
 * @property integer $id
 * @property integer $user_id
 * @property integer $item_id
 * @property double $lat
 * @property double $long
```

The two values $user_id and $item_id belong to other two tables:

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'user' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Users', 'user_id'),
        'item' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Items', 'item_id'),
    );
}
```

I defined some validator:

```
public function rules()
{
    // NOTE: you should only define rules for those attributes that
    // will receive user inputs.
    return array(
        array('user_id, item_id, lat, long', 'required'),

        array('item_id', 'exist', 'on'=>'create', 'attributeName'=>'id', 'className'=>'Items'),

        array('user_id, item_id', 'numerical', 'integerOnly'=>true),
        array('lat, long', 'numerical'),
        // The following rule is used by search().
        // Please remove those attributes that should not be searched.
        array('id, user_id, item_id, lat, long', 'safe', 'on'=>'search'),


    );
}
```

When in the actionCreate the method save() execute all the validators are working but not the one designed to check the presence of the external key in the model Items

```
array('item_id', 'exist', 'on'=>'create', 'attributeName'=>'id', 'className'=>'Items'),
```

And in case I try to save a Checkins that has a value in item_id without having the same id in the Items I don's any validation error.

Is this the right approach?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, it is the right approach if you want to assure that the item_id attribute need to have the corresponding id in the other table. Weirdly, I tried testing in my code and it worked fine. Are you sure that you didn't forget to set the scenario before saving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is most likely because you don't set the model's scenario to `'create'` before saving (I'm just guessing that, because you don't attach the `$checkin->save()` code in the controller's `actionCreate`.). The other validation worked most likely because they aren't set to a specific scenario (i.e. they will work in all validation.).

For example if there is no Item with id 5, the code below

```
    $checkin = new Checkin();
    $checkin->text = 'test';
    $checkin->item_id = 5;
    if (!$checkin->validate()){
        print_r($checkin->errors);
    }
```

will work normally since the `Checkin`'s scenario is not set to `'create'` (the default is `'insert'`). But I tried the code below

```
    $checkin = new Checkin();
    $checkin->scenario = 'create'; 
    //or you can set it in the instantiation 
    //$checkin = new Checkin('create');
    $checkin->text = 'test';
    $checkin->item_id = 5;
    if (!$checkin->validate()){
        print_r($checkin->errors);
    }
```

This will result a validation error.

Can you paste your model saving code?

Comment: Petra, thanks for your answer. Yes it's working now. It was not clear to me that the scenario in actionCreate() is not 'create' if you don't set it with $checkin->scenario = 'create'; Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark the question as `answered`.